# Streaming saved HLS videos using Nginx or Node

Tags: node.js, nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, hls.js

We have to stream stored HLS (.m3u8, not live) files to the clients on local server. Multiple clients requests multiple videos at the same time and the stored m3u8 segments have to be served from the server.

I'm seeing two alternatives

1) Streaming with nginx Live 
2) Using Nodejs or python app to stream the videos to clients.

I got confused with nginx and separate application server. Nginx also supporting some streaming without any application server. Can nginx work for streaming multiple stored videos for multiple clients or only for live streaming?

Nginx Tutorial::  https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/

Nodejs app: HLS server for serving stored m3u8 files  https://github.com/RationalCoding/hls-server

I tried nodeApp and its working fine and wanted to use nginx reverseproxy for this. But I find the streaming using nginx. So for my application should I go with node app streaming or nginx streaming? does this nginx support multiple streams at a time dynamically?

Any suggestions or documents helpful.

Comment: If its not live, any HTTP server (including Nginx) will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not live, then any webserver will work, as it is simply a bunch of small files. You do not need any special streaming support for this.

HLS for video on demand can be served from **any** plain webserver. Whether that is nginx, Apache, IIS or some homemade node server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use any HTTP server for serving static files. If you want to write some logic, then have to use application server. 
NGINX server conf for static HLS serving.

```
server {
    listen       8001;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /gcf-media {
        # Disable cache
        add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/dash+xml mpd;
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /Users/tarun/Desktop/labVideo;
    }
```

Now try 
localhost:8081/gcf-media/1/1.m3u8 in VLC or any client app